# How to execute XUnit tests via code

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

I have tests written in XUnit using InlineData and MemberData attributes. I would like to run tests via code elsewhere in my project and have the attributes automatically fill in test data like they normally do when ran through the VS test runner.

If it weren't for the attributes I would just call the methods directly like any other normal method. The asserts are still checked and it functions fine. But if I call a method directly that has the attributes, the attributes are ignored and I must provide all the test data manually through code. Is there some sort of test runner class in XUnit that I can reuse to accomplish this? I've been trying to dig through their API to no avail.

Why I want to do this will take some explanation, but bear with me. I'm writing tests against specific interfaces rather than their concrete implementations (think standard collection interfaces for example). There's plenty there to test and I don't want to copy paste them for each concrete implementer (could be dozens). I write the tests once and then pass each concrete implementation of the interface as the first argument to the test, a subject to test on.

But this leaves a problem. XUnit sees the test and wants to run it, but it can't because there are no concrete implementations available at this layer, there's only the interface. So I want to write tests at the higher layer that just new up the concrete implementations, and then invoke the interface tests passing in the new subjects. I can easily do this for tests that only accept 1 argument, the subject, but for tests where I'm using InlineData or MemberData too I would like to reuse those test cases already provided and just add the subject as the first argument.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to call the test methods yourself?

Comment: I add the explanation to the question because it took more than a few words words words. I hope it makes sense what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 15):

Available for reference is the GitHub issue [How to programmatically run XUnit tests](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/542) from the xUnit.net project.

The class `AssemblyRunner` is [now part of Xunit.Runner.Utility](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/2.4.1/src/xunit.runner.utility/Runners/AssemblyRunner.cs).

From the linked issue, xUnit.net contributor Brad Wilson provided a [sample runner](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/TestRunner/Program.cs) in the [samples.xunit project on GitHub](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit). This program demonstrates the techniques described in the issue. Namely, the portion responsible for running the tests after they have been discovered is as follows:

```
    using (var runner = AssemblyRunner.WithAppDomain(testAssembly))
    {
        runner.OnDiscoveryComplete = OnDiscoveryComplete;
        runner.OnExecutionComplete = OnExecutionComplete;
        runner.OnTestFailed = OnTestFailed;
        runner.OnTestSkipped = OnTestSkipped;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Discovering...");
        runner.Start(typeName);
        
        finished.WaitOne();  // A ManualResetEvent
        finished.Dispose();
        
        return result;
    }
```

For a deeper dive, he describes a method using `XunitFrontController` and `TestDiscoveryVisitor` to find and run tests. This is what `AssemblyRunner` does for its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Taking a closer look at XUnit's attribute hierarchy I found that the DataAttributes (InlineData, MemberData, etc) have a GetData method you can call to retrieve the set of data they represent. With a little reflection I can easily find all the tests in my test class and call the test methods, invoking the data attribute's get data method if there are any present, and perform the tests via my own code that way. The GetData part would have been much harder if I had to role my own version of it. Thank you XUnit authors for not forcing me to do that.